# Best way to update table if too many users access that table in sql with asp.net using c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I have a table and I have to update few columns of that table and with heavy traffic how to update that table so that do not effect the performance or any deadlock condition. Because multiple users will access the same table.

Answer (score 3):

You want to take a look at Isolation Levels, you can then make sure that your write process isn't affecting read processes.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms173763.aspx